# How to call useMap() outside of the file where <MapContainer> is NOT called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet.

For example I want to set bounds to map outside of the file where `<MapContainer>` is called.
For this I need to use `const map = useMap();`. How do I connect useMap() with the file where  was called?

Or to clarify even more.. I want to connect with the map outside of the map file to be enable to add/remove stuff. For example I want to enable markers outside of the file where `<MapContainer>` is called.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. While there shoud be some tricks to indeed "exfiltrate" map objects to ancestor component, so that you can manipulate them there, doing the reverse might be more logical: in the ancestor, manipulate the raw data that governs the map (typically the data for markers), and/or emit some events and manipulate the map accordingly in children. That way, your ancestor is agnostic to how the map is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ghybs is probably right in that you're probably thinking of doing something that doesn't truly require the `L.map` object in an ancestor of the `MapContainer`.  Especially if you're simply talking about using map `Marker` components - theyre only ever useful as children of a map.  That being said, what you're talking about doing is simple to set up. An example of how to make the underlying `L.map` object available is right there in the [react-leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/).

A quick example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [mapRef, setMapref] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <Map setMapRef={setMapRef} />
      <SomewhereElse mapRef={mapRef} />
    </>
  )
}

const Map = ({ setMapRef }) => {
  return <MapContainer whenCreated={setMapRef} />
}
```

Once the `MapContainer` loads the leafletmap, `whenCreated` is fired, which then fires the callback `setMapRef`.  The `L.map` instance is now saved to the `mapRef` state variable in `App`, and is available there to be used `SomewhereElse`.

Comment: Hmm I still can't get it to work.. Could you give me a working example how do you add marker on <SomewhereElse>, which is located in another file?

Comment: I think its probably better if you show some code, show what you are attempting, and then we can debug from there.  I have no idea what you're trying to do when you say you are trying to add a marker from SomewhereElse.  react-lealfet components don't work unless they're descendants of the map. It doesn't make much sense in an application to try to add react-leaflet components to the map *outside* of the map component.